# Isabelle simplifier introduces case distinction for if-statement (why? when?)

Tags: isabelle

If I apply the simp-method to a goal containing an if-expression, the simplifier automatically introduces a case distinction:

```
lemma "undefined (if x then True else False)"
  apply simp
```

This gives the goal:

```
(x ⟶ undefined True) ∧ (¬ x ⟶ undefined False)
```

My question is: How is the simplifier told to do this? I could find a simplifier-rule for if that would conceivable lead to this behavior, nor a simproc. How can I get a similar behavior for other if-like constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is enabled by the *splitter*. The simplifier itself is a big loop that not only performs rewriting, but also afterwards a variety of other things, before it starts rewriting again.

For if, the relevant `split` rules are `if_splits`:

```
?P (if ?Q then ?x else ?y) = ((?Q ⟶ ?P ?x) ∧ (¬ ?Q ⟶ ?P ?y))
?P (if ?Q then ?x else ?y) = (¬ (?Q ∧ ¬ ?P ?x ∨ ¬ ?Q ∧ ¬ ?P ?y))
```

The first `split` rule applies to an occurrence of `if _ then _ else _` in the conclusion, the latter for an occurrence in a premise. (Both rules are available separately as `if_split` and `if_split_asm`.)

`case` constants for data types have similar rules, e.g. `bool.splits`:

```
?P (case ?bool of True ⇒ ?f1.0 | False ⇒ ?f2.0) =
  ((?bool = True ⟶ ?P ?f1.0) ∧ (?bool = False ⟶ ?P ?f2.0))
?P (case ?bool of True ⇒ ?f1.0 | False ⇒ ?f2.0) =
  (¬ (?bool = True ∧ ¬ ?P ?f1.0 ∨ ?bool = False ∧ ¬ ?P ?f2.0))
```

Rules can be declared as `split` rules by annotating them with `[split]`.

More information can be found in §9.3.1 of the [reference manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/isar-ref.pdf). The whole subsection §9.3 explains the simplifier in more detail (although admittedly much knowledge about the simplifier is basically "ancient wisdom").

Comment: An interesting fact: those rules seem not to apply when rewriting terms (e.g., via `Simplifier.rewrite`), only when rewriting subgoals (e.g., via `simp_tac`).